# My Vue store is blowing up my memory usage when using the infinite loading component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asp.net-core, vue-component, vuex

New to Vue and are using a infinite loader plugin to load more results when the bottom of the page is hit. It loads about 50 results with a viewmodel that has about 6 properties in it. So the total data size sent over the network is about 18kb, not very big. But when the new fetched data gets pushed to the store it blows up the memory footprint by 30-50MB. And it does this each time we fetch! After just a few fetches IE bombs out and becomes very slow.

Here is a couple of snippets to show what we are doing

in the axios/ajax response we push the data to the Vue data store

```js
}).then(response => {
  this.list.push(...response.data)
  // tried below but still blows up memory and speed
  this.list = [].concat(this.list, response.data);
})

// in the list getter/setter
list: {
  get() {
    return this.$store.state.records.list
  },
  set(value) {
    this.$store.commit('records/listUpdate', value)
  }
},
```

And in my index.js file I have the mutation/action stuff like this

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const appRoot = {
  ...
}

const records = {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    witnessName: null,
    sourceCode: null,
    startDate: null,
    startDateFormatted: null,
    endDate: null,
    endDateFormatted: null,
    jobsiteCode: null,
    jobsiteName: null,
    defendantCode: null,
    defendantName: null,
    shipName: null,
    info: null,
    createdBy: null,
    recordId: null,
    pageSize: 50,
    list: [],
    distance: -Infinity,
    pagination: {
      sortBy: 'sourceCode',
      descending: false,
      rowsPerPage: -1
    },
    defaultSortBy: 'sourceCode',
    defaultDescending: false,
    showList: false,
    lastClickedId: null,
    lastViewedId: null,
    refListIndex: null,
    refList: [],
    // recordProducts
    recordProductsList: [],
    recordProductsDistance: -Infinity,
    recordProductsPagination: {
      sortBy: 'defendantCode',
      descending: false,
      rowsPerPage: -1
    },
    recordProductsDefaultSortBy: 'defendantCode',
    recordProductsDefaultDescending: false,
    recordProductsShowList: false,
    recordProductsLastClickedId: null,
    recordProductsLastViewedId: null,
    recordProductsRefListIndex: null,
    recordProductsRefList: [],
    // recordCoworkers
    recordCoworkersList: [],
    recordCoworkersDistance: -Infinity,
    recordCoworkersPagination: {
      sortBy: 'coworkerName',
      descending: false,
      rowsPerPage: -1
    },
    recordCoworkersDefaultSortBy: 'coworkerName',
    recordCoworkersDefaultDescending: false,
    recordCoworkersShowList: false,
    recordCoworkersLastClickedId: null,
    recordCoworkersLastViewedId: null,
    recordCoworkersRefListIndex: null,
    recordCoworkersRefList: [],
  },
  mutations: {
    witnessNameUpdate(state, value) {
      state.witnessName = value
    },
    sourceCodeUpdate(state, value) {
      state.sourceCode = value
    },
    startDateUpdate(state, value) {
      state.startDate = value
    },
    startDateFormattedUpdate(state, value) {
      state.startDateFormatted = value
    },
    endDateUpdate(state, value) {
      state.endDate = value
    },
    endDateFormattedUpdate(state, value) {
      state.endDateFormatted = value
    },
    jobsiteCodeUpdate(state, value) {
      state.jobsiteCode = value
    },
    jobsiteNameUpdate(state, value) {
      state.jobsiteName = value
    },
    defendantCodeUpdate(state, value) {
      state.defendantCode = value
    },
    defendantNameUpdate(state, value) {
      state.defendantName = value
    },
    shipNameUpdate(state, value) {
      state.shipName = value
    },
    infoUpdate(state, value) {
      state.info = value
    },
    createdByUpdate(state, value) {
      state.createdBy = value
    },
    recordIdUpdate(state, value) {
      state.recordId = value
    },
    listUpdate(state, value) {
      state.list = value
    },
    distanceUpdate(state, value) {
      state.distance = value
    },
    paginationUpdate(state, value) {
      state.pagination = value
    },
    defaultSortByUpdate(state, value) {
      state.defaultSortBy = value
    },
    defaultDescendingUpdate(state, value) {
      state.defaultDescending = value
    },
    showListUpdate(state, value) {
      state.showList = value
    },
    lastClickedIdUpdate(state, value) {
      state.lastClickedId = value
    },
    lastViewedIdUpdate(state, value) {
      state.lastViewedId = value
    },
    refListIndexUpdate(state, value) {
      state.refListIndex = value
    },
    refListUpdate(state, value) {
      state.refList = value
    },
    // recordWitnesses
    recordWitnessesListUpdate(state, value) {
      state.recordWitnessesList = value
    },
    recordWitnessesDistanceUpdate(state, value) {
      state.recordWitnessesDistance = value
    },
    recordWitnessesPaginationUpdate(state, value) {
      state.recordWitnessesPagination = value
    },
    recordWitnessesDefaultSortByUpdate(state, value) {
      state.recordWitnessesDefaultSortBy = value
    },
    recordWitnessesDefaultDescendingUpdate(state, value) {
      state.recordWitnessesDefaultDescending = value
    },
    recordWitnessesShowListUpdate(state, value) {
      state.recordWitnessesShowList = value
    },
    recordWitnessesLastClickedIdUpdate(state, value) {
      state.recordWitnessesLastClickedId = value
    },
    recordWitnessesLastViewedIdUpdate(state, value) {
      state.recordWitnessesLastViewedId = value
    },
    recordWitnessesRefListIndexUpdate(state, value) {
      state.recordWitnessesRefListIndex = value
    },
    recordWitnessesRefListUpdate(state, value) {
      state.recordWitnessesRefList = value
    },
    // recordProducts
    recordProductsListUpdate(state, value) {
      state.recordProductsList = value
    },
    recordProductsDistanceUpdate(state, value) {
      state.recordProductsDistance = value
    },
    recordProductsPaginationUpdate(state, value) {
      state.recordProductsPagination = value
    },
    recordProductsDefaultSortByUpdate(state, value) {
      state.recordProductsDefaultSortBy = value
    },
    recordProductsDefaultDescendingUpdate(state, value) {
      state.recordProductsDefaultDescending = value
    },
    recordProductsShowListUpdate(state, value) {
      state.recordProductsShowList = value
    },
    recordProductsLastClickedIdUpdate(state, value) {
      state.recordProductsLastClickedId = value
    },
    recordProductsLastViewedIdUpdate(state, value) {
      state.recordProductsViewedClickedId = value
    },
    recordProductsRefListIndex(state, value) {
      state.recordProductsRefListIndex = value
    },
    recordProductsRefList(state, value) {
      state.recordProductsRefList = value
    },
    recordCoworkersListUpdate(state, value) {
      state.recordCoworkersList = value
    },
    recordCoworkersDistanceUpdate(state, value) {
      state.recordCoworkersDistance = value
    },
    recordCoworkersPaginationUpdate(state, value) {
      state.recordCoworkersPagination = value
    },
    recordCoworkersDefaultSortByUpdate(state, value) {
      state.recordCoworkersDefaultSortBy = value
    },
    recordCoworkersDefaultDescendingUpdate(state, value) {
      state.recordCoworkersDefaultDescending = value
    },
    recordCoworkersShowListUpdate(state, value) {
      state.recordCoworkersShowList = value
    },
    recordCoworkersLastClickedIdUpdate(state, value) {
      state.recordCoworkersLastClickedId = value
    },
    recordCoworkersLastViewedIdUpdate(state, value) {
      state.recordCoworkersLastViewedId = value
    },
    recordCoworkersRefListIndexUpdate(state, value) {
      state.recordCoworkersRefListIndex = value
    },
    recordCoworkersRefListUpdate(state, value) {
      state.recordCoworkersRefList = value
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your mutation/action for the list?

Comment: Hi Steven. I've updated my answer with more js to show the 'state' and mutations.